# server Started on Port: undefined in undefinedmode

Tags: node.js, node-modules, nodejs-server, node-debugger, node-dev

```
const app=require('./app')

const dotenv =require('dotenv');
const PORT=3000;
 

dotenv.config({path:'backend/config/config.env'})

app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`server Started on Port: ${process.env.PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV}mode`);

})

const app=require('./app')

const dotenv =require('dotenv');
const PORT=3000;
 

dotenv.config({path:'backend/config/config.env'})

app.listen(process.env.PORT,()=>{
    console.log(`server Started on Port: ${process.env.PORT} in ${process.env.NODE_ENV}mode`);

})
```

I am getting error as follows:

> server Started on Port: undefined in undefined mode

Comment: what PORT number you have assigned in your environment file ?

Comment: PORT=3000;
NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT;

Comment: @BuzS if those are the verbatim contents of your environment file, you're using an invalid syntax.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make a file on the root say `local.env` of your project and assign variable values in that.

```
PORT=3000
NODE_ENV=DEVELOPMENT
```